# Why does this code generate Notice: Undefined index?

Tags: php

This code is not pretty, but I want to print out the last generated Auto Incremented ID from the table `studentcourseplan`

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['session_username']) ) { header ("Location: login.php");exit;} //If user in not signed in, redirect to login page

include("dbconfig.php");

if (isset($_POST['course_id'])) {

    $course_id = $_POST['course_id'];
    $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
    
    $studentcourseplan_update = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO studentcourseplan (student_id,cpl_startdate, cpl_enddate, cpl_coursename, cpl_pricevalue)
      SELECT '$student_id','$start_date', '$end_date', course_name, price_value
        FROM courses c
        INNER JOIN pricegroups p ON p.price_id = c.course_price_id
      WHERE c.course_id = '$course_id'");
      
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM studentcourseplan");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $cpl_id = $row['cpl_id'];
    
    $studentcourseplanelements_update = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO studentcourseplanelements (scpe_cpl_id, scpe_name, scpe_days)
      SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), cp.plan_name, cp.plan_time FROM courses c
        INNER JOIN course_to_plan cpl   ON cpl.course_id = c.course_id
        INNER JOIN courseplans cp       ON cp.plan_id = cpl.plan_id
    WHERE cpl.course_id = '$course_id'");
    
    $courseinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentcourseplan WHERE cpl_id = '$cpl_id'") or die(mysql_error());

    if ($studentcourseplan_update === true) {
        
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($courseinfo)) {
            echo $result['cpl_id'];
        }
        
    } else if ($studentcourseplan_update === false){
        echo "Kunde inte uppdatera.";
    }
}
?>
```

It whines on line 24 which is:

```
$cpl_id = $row['cpl_id'];
```

I get:

> Undefined index: cpl_id in \Path\To\Page.php on line 24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have selected only `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the first select query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM studentcourseplan");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
// Doesn't exist, only $row['LAST_INSERT_ID()']
$cpl_id = $row['cpl_id'];
// Probably you meant
$cpl_id = $row['LAST_INSERT_ID()'];
```

#### But the above is unnecessary.

Instead, you can just call [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) rather than executing a query to retrieve it.

```
$cpl_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

#### Note about security:

Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection in its current form.  Be sure to call `mysql_real_escape_string()` over all the `$_POST` vars used as query inputs.

```
$course_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course_id']);
$student_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['student_id']);
$start_date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['start_date']);
$end_date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['end_date']);
```

In the long run, it's recommended to migrate away from the `mysql_*()` functions and instead learn to use a more modern API supporting prepared statements like PDO or MySQLi.